# How to make Items in ListView editable via interface

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView (shown below) that has a list of ingredients and how much of each ingredient each item has. How can I make it so there is some way to edit the number value when clicking on each ingredient?

[image]

Context menu and alert dialog so far, I also considered buttons to match the items but discovered it didn't work with the infinite listview. Thank you to anyone who helps me with this!

Comment: You want to change the number, just by clicking on an item? Or do you want to say like open a dialog box and edit values and fetch value from dialog and update the list?

Comment: the latter is the goal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the these values then you can create a child class and create list of this of child class.
you can use the onItemClickListner to update the value in the object and then do notifydatasetchange on the adapter this will do the trick.

or

Alternatively you can pass the two list in the adapter and update the list you want to update and do notifydatasetchange.

for e.g.:-

```
//MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView recView;
ArrayList<Childclass> chobj=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.recView);

    chobj.add(new Childclass("Tomato sauce","0.0"));
    chobj.add(new Childclass("Chicken","0.0"));
    chobj.add(new Childclass("Olives","0.0"));

    ListAdapter lstadptr=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this,chobj);
    recView.setAdapter(lstadptr);

    recView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit1);

            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Custom dialog");
            dialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter text below");
            dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //do something with edt.getText().toString();
                    chobj.get(position).setQuantity(edt.getText().toString());
                    ((ListAdapter) recView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    //pass
                }
            });
            AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
            b.show();

        }
    });

}}
```

Child Class

```
public class Childclass {

String name;
String quantity;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Childclass(String name, String quantity) {

    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}}
```

ListAdapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

ArrayList<Childclass> chobj;
Context context;

public ListAdapter(@NonNull Context context,ArrayList<Childclass> chobj) {
    super(context, R.layout.recyclerow, chobj);
    this.context = context;
    this.chobj = chobj;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View v;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerow, parent, false);
    TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtrow);
    TextView tv1= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtrow1);

    tv.setText(chobj.get(position).getName());
    tv1.setText(chobj.get(position).getQuantity());

    return v;
}}
```

activity main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.abhishek.kotlinprojecttest.MainActivity">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/recView">

</ListView>
```

custom alert

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

list row

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowcd">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="listTExt"
        android:id="@+id/txtrow"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="listTExt"
        android:id="@+id/txtrow1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Hope this will help you